# place first element next to centered element

Tags: html, css

I have this simple layout:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.el1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.el2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="el1">element 1</span>
  <span class="el2">element 2</span>
</div>
```

I want, that `element2` is centered in the container first, and `element1` is always next to it, regardless the size of `element2` (`element2` can have different sizes).

I tried with `position: absolute` and auto margin on `element2` and moving `element1` left, but in this way, if `element2` grows, I have to adjust also `element1`.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't how you prefer the "element 1" to be, but I'm assuming its width would be not as flexible as the "element 2". Have a look on code below, especially on the comment for the `.el1` width.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .container {
      align-items: center;
      background-color: gray;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .el1 {
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      width: 100%; /* The value of 100% in here means it's going to match the "element 2" width. So adjust this value accordingly. */
    }
    .el2 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="el1">element 1</span>
        <span class="el2">element 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to reverse the order of the flex, you can use `flex-direction:row-reverse` in your case

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.el1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.el2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="el1">element 1</span>
  <span class="el2">element 2</span>
</div>
```